# How to make a table having words and phrases as entries?

Tags: tables

I was making some tables for the documentation but this particular table struck me. It has entries in a form of sentences and phrases as shown in the figure below....

[image]

I made that table using Microsoft Word but I wonder if we can do the same in Latex...

My question is...

> Can we make the same table as above using Latex? If yes...how?

Update: There is one good answerer that showed how it is done, but for some unknown reasons, when I copy and pasted the poster's code, the PDF output looks awful...like this below...

[image]

How to resolve it? It is close to what I want....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution based on `tabularx` and `enumitem`. Note you don't really need `multirow` here.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx, caption}
\captionsetup{skip=6pt}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 

   \begin{table}[!htb]
    \sffamily\small
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \centering
    \caption{Some caption} \label{table-test}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{1.4cm}|p{1.5cm}| >{\compress\RaggedRight}X|*{3}{p{21mm}|}}
    \hline
    Test case & Action & ~Test procedure & Expected result & Actual result & Remarks\\
    \hline
    {Login} & User login & 
    \begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, itemsep=0pt, after=\leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr\topsep+\partopsep}]
    \item Provide username and password
    \item Validate all fields have been filled
    \item Goes to the Main Site
    \end{enumerate}
    & Successfully
    logged in & Successfully logged in & Logged in \\
    \cline{2-2} \cline{4-6}
    & Missing credentials & & ... & ... & Cannot log in\\[3cm]
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hey...uhmmm how do you put a caption on the table above?

Comment: @zZ_LateX_HaterZ_zZ: You have to nest  `the code in a `table` environment  and add `\caption{...}\label{xxx}` (the latter for cross-references). Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, it is hard to convince LaTeX to create such an unappealing table, but of course it can be done. ;-)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\begin{document}
\sffamily\small
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|p{1cm}|@{}p{3cm}|*{3}{p{2.5cm}|}}
\hline
Test case & Action & ~Test procedure & Expected result & Actual result & Remarks\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{=}{Login} & User login & \multirow{2}{=}{
\begin{enumerate}
\item Provide username and password
\item Validate all fields have been filled
\item Goes to the Main Site
\end{enumerate}
} & Successfully
logged in & Successfully logged in & logged in \\[3cm]
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-6}
& Missing credentials & & \dots & \dots & Cannot log in\\[3cm]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I copy and pasted your code, the PDF output looks odd.

Comment: @zZ_LateX_HaterZ_zZ  I guess you copied only the table, not the `10pt` in `\documentclass[10pt]{article}` nor `\sffamily\small`.  To very first approximation you may just make the third column wider, e.g. `@{}p{5cm}` instead of `@{}p{3cm}`.

Comment: I copied all your code you've typed....yes....

Comment: @zZ_LateX_HaterZ_zZ Strange. Which LaTeX distribution do you use? I use TeXLive 2018, which I update on a regular basis, and compile the above with pdflatex.

Comment: I did what you've said. The third column did widened, but the entries in the third column still looked the same....it's still awkward...

Comment: @zZ_LateX_HaterZ_zZ This is really strange and I have no explanation. Hope some TeX guru sees that... ;-)

Comment: hmmm...I use Texmaker to make PDF's....but some commenters noticed that I had some outdated Latex distribution called MikTex (they say it's 3 years old already)....and I have Biber version 1.5 which is already 5 years old....

Comment: My softwares are dinosaurs....never been updated...

Comment: @zZ_LateX_HaterZ_zZ I thought dinosaurs have died out. ;-) This is a conceivable explanation, yet I should add that the packages I load are also quite old and I was not aware that they changed (that much).

Comment: @zZ_LateX_HaterZ_zZ _all_ questions are clearer if they have a complete small document as marmot used in this answer. If you think things are not working, post a version of the document here to your question, and show the log file or output screenshot

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes....I will...I'm going to make a small working example that uses marmot's code and this document is what I had used to make something, like a senior thesis...

Comment: @zZ_LateX_HaterZ_zZ you should edit this question not ask a new one, but I would guess that you have a pre-2016 multirow package which does not have the `=` option.  If you get a tex error you should ask about the _error_ not about the pdf output (which is usually just arbitrary nonsense after an error) your list looks to be set in a column of width 0. Simply update your tex distribution via miktex's package manager.